# Error on commented-out code

Tags: javascript, c#

wonderful coders. I'm getting an error on commented-out code. The error is as below:

[image]

Previously I had controls with IDs #datepicker1 and #datepicker2, then I decided to no longer need them, so I removed them in code, and removed the Javascript that manipulated them.

The odd thing is that this code works in Debug, but throws the exception when deployed and run from a server.

Thanks

Comment: Use `Ctrl` + `K` + `C` to comment out the code in visual studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That will only comment out the JavaScript, not the ASP.NET tag. I would just use source control and delete the lines.

Comment: I also commented out the ASP.NET tag

Answer (score 3):

That error isn't coming from your JavaScript, it's happening on the server side. (In `datepicker1.ClientID`).

If you don't want to run that code, you'll need to use a server side comment (`<%-- --%>` in ASP.NET). Or delete the line entirely.